# How to show that $\int_0^\pi \arcsin{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}\right)}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to show that
$$\int_0^\pi \arcsin{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}\right)}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Context: I was working on [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594297/in-a-circle-where-should-you-draw-a-line-segment-of-fixed-length-to-maximize-t) ("Attempt $2$") and miscopied an integral, so I was trying to evaluate the integral in my question here. Anyway, now I'm intrigued by this integral, because my computer strongly suggests that it has a closed form, $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

My attempt: I have tried substituting $u=\cos{x}$ or $u=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}$, and the [half-angle tangent substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/half-angle-tangent-substitution/), but they do not seem to work.

(Ideally, there is an elementary solution, but any solution would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One can show that $\sin(x)/\sqrt{5/4-\cos(x)}$ increases from $0$ to $1$ for $x$ going from $0$ to $\pi/3$ and decreases from $1$ to $0$ for $x$ going from $\pi/3$ to $\pi$. Then the integral can be separated into
\begin{align}
 I&=\int_0^\pi \arcsin{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}\right)}\,dx\\
 &=\int_0^{\pi/3} \arcsin{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}\right)}\,dx+\int_{\pi/3}^\pi \arcsin{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}\right)}\,dx
\end{align}
We define
\begin{equation}
 u=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5/4-\cos{x}}}
\end{equation}
or $u^2(5/4-\cos{x})=1-\cos^2x$.
Solving this equation for $\cos x$,

- for $0\le x\le\pi/3$, we have $\cos x=(u^2+\sqrt{u^4-5u^2+4})/2$
- for $\pi/3\le x\le\pi$, we have $\cos x=(u^2-\sqrt{u^4-5u^2+4})/2$.

Substituting $u$ into the integral, it comes
\begin{align}
 I&=\int_0^1\arcsin(u)\frac{\sqrt{5-2 u^{2}-2 \sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}}{\sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}\,du\\
&+\int_0^1\arcsin(u)\frac{\sqrt{5-2 u^{2}+2 \sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}}{\sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}\,du\\
 &=\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin(u)}{\sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}
 f(u)\,du
\end{align}
where $f(u)=\sqrt{5-2 u^{2}-2 \sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}+\sqrt{5-2 u^{2}+2 \sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}$.

Now, it is possible to simplify:
\begin{align}
 \left[f(u)\right]^2&=10-4u^2+2\sqrt{5-2 u^{2}-2 \sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}\sqrt{5-2 u^{2}+2 \sqrt{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}\\
 &=4(4-u^2)
\end{align}
and
\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{\frac{4(4-u^2)}{u^{4}-5 u^{2}+4}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
 I&=2\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\
&=\left.\arcsin^2(x)\right|_0^1\\
 &=\frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align}
as expected.

Comment: Awesome solution! Check the following question when you have time.                                                           https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568778/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-ln-left-fracx12x2-rig

Answer (score 2):

Leveraging the identity $\arcsin x = \arctan \dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and applying some substitutions leads to a trivial integral:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\pi \arcsin \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\frac54 - \cos x}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi \arctan \frac{2\sin x}{\lvert1-2\cos x\rvert} \, dx \\
&= \left\{\int_0^\tfrac\pi3 - \int_\tfrac\pi3^\pi\right\} \arctan \frac{\sin x}{\cos x-\frac12} \, dx \\
&= \left\{\int_0^\tfrac1{\sqrt3} - \int_\tfrac1{\sqrt3}^\infty\right\} \frac{2 \arctan \frac{4t}{1-3t^2}}{1+t^2} \, dt & t = \tan \frac x2 \\
&= \left\{\int_0^1 - \int_1^\infty\right\} \frac{2\sqrt3 \, \arctan \left(\frac4{\sqrt3} \frac{t}{1-t^2}\right)}{3+t^2} \, dt & t\to\frac t{\sqrt3} \\
&= \int_0^1 2\sqrt3 \, \left(\frac1{3+t^2} + \frac1{1+3t^2}\right) \arctan \left(\frac4{\sqrt3} \frac{t}{1-t^2}\right) \, dt & t\to\frac1t \text{ for } t>1 \\
&= \int_0^1 2\sqrt3 \, \frac{1+u^2}{1+u^2+u^4} \arctan \frac{1-u^2}{\sqrt3\,u} \, du & u=\frac{1-t}{1+t} \\
&= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 2v \, dv = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}4} & \tan v=\frac{1-u^2}{\sqrt3\,u}
\end{align*}$$